# Parsing text with regex for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing a text file that contains thousands of articles in the following format, all following the exact same pattern. The text is between the dashed lines.

```
-------------------------------
 1 of 40 DOCUMENTS



                  July 22, 2016  9:42 



This is the title of the document.



Author 1 and Author 2 in London



This is the body of the text. This paragraph has four sentences. There are 25 words in total. The meaning of the words is not important.



July 23, 2016

 --------------------
```

I would like to process these articles and keep only:

a) line 1 with the document number, 
b) the title, and 
c) the body of the text

How can I express this in regex, as the body of the text may also contain dates which I would like to keep? Any alternative suggestions would be welcome too. Thank you for your help.

I am looking to get each article to have the following format, with text between the dashed lines.

```
-------------------------------
  1 of 40 DOCUMENTS



This is the title of the document.



This is the body of the text. This paragraph has four sentences. There are 25 words in total. The meaning of the words is not important.

--------------------------------
```

Comment: also about the authors, are they coming enumerated like that? Or is it like ABCD, John; EFG, Dave in <anyLocation>?

Comment: You have a problem that you don't know how to solve and yet you are proposing the tool, i.e. regex to solve it. Have you considered that perhaps regex is *not* the best tool for this problem? Perhaps that is why you haven't event attempted to solve it.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/m7owVW/1

Comment: @IWHKYB: The authors are not in alphabetical order. For some articles there is a single author, for others it can be two or three authors. The location of the authors comes after their name. All this information is in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using regular expressions may be the best way to solve this problem.

This is a rough idea of how one could approach this problem. The function `transform` expects to be passed an iterator that returns one input line at a time. This can just be an open file. For testing purposes I have split a test string on into a list of lines and passed an iterator for that list. The function, a generator, might need some fine tuning depending on how many blank lines you may want to delete from the input. For testing purposes, I have added a second article to the input as if it were the last one. I took a guess on how it might be terminated.

The generator function iterates through all the lines that are passed to it in variable `lines`, which is an iterable object, by executing `next(lines)` and assigning the result to variable `line`. If the current line is to be included in the output, then statement `yield line` is executed. I have implemented the solution in terms of what you want to delete rather than what you want to keep,since it is not at all clear from your limited example what all the possibilities for titles and text bodies are. It appears you wish to delete the 6th and 14th lines counting from '----------- etc.' being the first line and the date that appears two lines before the next '--------- etc. '. If that date on the 6th line and list of authors on the 14th line are not always in those fixed line positions, then all bets are off.

Can you precisely describe the format of the input?

```
import re


def transform(lines):
    try:
        line = None
        while True:
            if line is None:
                line = next(lines) # ---------------
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # 1 of 40 documents
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # July 22, 2016 9:42 - Do not yield this line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # This is the title of the document.
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # blank line
            yield line
            line = next(lines) # Author 1 and Author 2 in London - Do not yield this line
            while True:
                line = next(lines)
                if not re.match(r'\s*[A-Za-z]+\s+\d\d?,\s+\d{4}\s*$', line): # date?
                    yield line
                else:
                    line2 = next(lines) # blank ?
                    line3 = next(lines) # ------------------------------- ?
                    if line3 != '-------------------------------':
                        yield line
                        yield line2
                        yield line3
                    else:
                        line = line3
                        break # start of new document
    except StopIteration:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    text = """-------------------------------
 1 of 40 DOCUMENTS



                  July 22, 2016  9:42



This is the title of the document.



Author 1 and Author 2 in London



This is the body of the text. This paragraph has four sentences. There are 25 words in total. The meaning of the words is not important.



July 23, 2016

-------------------------------
  1 of 40 DOCUMENTS



                  July 22, 2016  9:42



This is the title of the document.



Author 1 and Author 2 in London



This is the body of the text. This paragraph has four sentences. There are 25 words in total. The meaning of the words is not important.



July 23, 2016
"""
    for line in transform(iter(text.split('\n'))):
        print(line)
```

And the resulting ouput:

```
-------------------------------
 1 of 40 DOCUMENTS






This is the title of the document.






This is the body of the text. This paragraph has four sentences. There are 25 words in total. The meaning of the words is not important.



-------------------------------
  1 of 40 DOCUMENTS






This is the title of the document.






This is the body of the text. This paragraph has four sentences. There are 25 words in total. The meaning of the words is not important.
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a try. I am a finance/statistics person trying to solve coding issues... After spending a lot of time on the web, regex was suggested as possible solution. There might be other solutions I am sure. I'll try this one first.

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide more explanation as to how the code works. To understand it fully, you need to understand Python generator functions.